# How do I make the circle bigger than the arcs inside without going off center?

Tags: java, geometry

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class fourfans extends JFrame {
public fourfans(){
    setTitle("DrawArcs");
    add(new ArcsPanel());
    add(new ArcsPanel());
    add(new ArcsPanel());
    add(new ArcsPanel());

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fourfans frame = new fourfans();
    GridLayout test = new GridLayout(2,2);
    frame.setLayout(test);
    frame.setSize(250 , 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}


}


class ArcsPanel extends JPanel{

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    int radius = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

    int x = xCenter - radius;
    int y = yCenter - radius;

    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);
    g.drawOval(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);       
}
}
```

Every time I try to change the 2 * radius to 2.1 * Radius, it wont let me because that is a double. Then when I put in a fixed number that is larger than the arcs, it makes the circle off center.

Comment: `2.1f * radius` ? `(int)(2.1 * radius)` ?

Comment: @Patashu that seems to have fixed the double problem, but that doesn't fix my circle being offcenter.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why putting in a number larger than the arcs makes your circle go off center is because Java has you plugin the top left corner as x,y rather than the origin of the circle/circle arcs. So if you make one of them bigger you have to recalculate what its x and y would be, for example

```
int radius = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);
int radiusOval = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4 * 1.05);

int x = xCenter - radius;
int y = yCenter - radius;
int xOval = xCenter - radiusOval;
int yOval = yCenter - radiusOval;

g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);
g.drawOval(xOval, yOval, (int)(2.1 * radius), (int)(2.1 * radius));
```